# color text in bibliography text

Tags: bibliographies, color

I am trying to make blue color text in some of the bibliography. I have tried with the following code. It does not work. Please help me.

```
//myReference.bib file

@article{nature,
author = {\color{blue}Rosa Rademakers and Manuela Neumann and Ian R. Mackenzie}},
title = {\color{blue}Advances in understanding the molecular basis of frontotemporal dementia - elongated title}},
journal = {\color{blue} {Nature Reviews Neurology}},
volume = {\color{blue}{8}},
year = {\color{blue}{2012}},
pages = {\color{blue}{423-434}},
doi = {\color{blue}{10.1038/nrneurol.2012.117}},
}

@article{fuente,
author = {D. de la Fuente and J.G. Castaño and M. Morcillo},
title = {Long-term atmospheric corrosion of zinc},
journal = {Corrosion Science},
volume = {49},
year = {2007},
pages = {1420–1436},
}



\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is my document \cite{nature} and we have another \cite{fuente}
\bibliography{myReference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "does not work" isn't very helpful description, do you get an error or wrong colours or ... at the very least your example document needs the color package

Answer (score 3):

It seems, the whole entry should be colored blue. Therefore the following example redefines `\bibitem` to look for `nature`. If it is found, the entry is set in blue. This way, bibtex is not confused by color markup inside bibliography entries.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myReference.bib}
@article{nature,
  author = {Rosa Rademakers and Manuela Neumann and Ian R. Mackenzie}},
  title = {Advances in understanding the molecular basis of frontotemporal
           dementia - elongated title}},
  journal = {{Nature Reviews Neurology}},
  volume = {8},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {423-434},
  doi = {10.1038/nrneurol.2012.117},
}
@article{fuente,
  author = {D. de la Fuente and J.G. Castaño and M. Morcillo},
  title = {Long-term atmospheric corrosion of zinc},
  journal = {Corrosion Science},
  volume = {49},
  year = {2007},
  pages = {1420–1436},
}
@article{xy,
  author = {Xaver Zorro},
  title = {Vampires},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\myorg@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{bibitem@#1}{%
    \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
  }{%
    \begingroup
      \color{\csname bibitem@#1\endcsname}%
      \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\bibitem@nature}{blue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is my document \cite{nature} and we have another \cite{fuente}
and \cite{xy}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myReference}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]