# Different color for specific references using Bibtex with revtex4-1

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, color, revtex

I am trying to mark changes to a LaTeX document in a specific color, and hence need certain references in color as well.  I have no idea how to achieve this, other than editing specific entries in my `.bib` file. This is undesirable, as I might need to use the same .bib file without this requirement in the future.

Here is what my `.tex` file looks like

```
\documentclass[aip,jcp,preprint,amssymb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mychange}[1]{{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\begin{document}

I want citations `\cite{R1}`, `\cite{R2}`, and `\cite{R3}` such that `\cite{R2}` is in `\mychange{blue}`.

\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding `main.bib` file looks like

```
@article{R1,
  Title                    = {My first reference},
  Author                   = {Author1},
  Journal                  = {Journal1},
  Year                     = {2017},
}
@article{R2,
  Title                    = {My second reference in blue},
  Author                   = {Author2 and Author3},
  Journal                  = {Journal2},
  Year                     = {2000},
}
@article{R3,
  Title                    = {My last reference},
  Author                   = {Author4},
  Journal                  = {Journal1},
  Year                     = {2010},
}
```

The desired output is

[image: Desired output]

I compile this using the sequence `latex->bibtex->latex->latex->dvips->ps2pdf` to generate the pdf.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? If at all possible, I would like to consistently use the defined `\mychange{}` command. I am limited to document class `revtex4-1` due to requirements of the journal involved.

Note that the answer to [Different style/color for some specific references using natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226389) compiles but does not show the required color when I remove `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` (and remove `\usepackage{natbib}`). The answer to [color text in bibliography text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188153/136667) also fails to compile when the bibtex key has numbers involved (e.g., changing the key nature to nature1980). Also, [Different style/color for some specific references using Bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224582/136667) only changes the label, and not the entry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.